# Stop AVPlayer from playing in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avplayer

I'm using `AVPlayer` for displaying video in my `TableViewCell`. It is playing in `TableViewCell` , but the problem is that I'm not able to stop it.
I've used this Code to play video in cellforRow

```
        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: cell.videoview.frame.origin.x, y: cell.videoview.frame.origin.x, width:cell.videoview.frame.size.width, height: cell.videoview.frame.size.height)
        cell.videoview.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        avPlayer?.play()
```

The `avPlayer` and `playerLayer` are defined in the `viewController` like this

```
var avPlayer  : AVPlayer?
var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
```

I'm using this code to stop the video

```
    self.avPlayer?.pause()
    self.playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    self.avPlayer?.rate = 0.0
    self.avPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
    self.avPlayer = nil
```

My question is this how can I stop the video running through `AVPlayer` on `AVPlayerLayer`?
Please suggest a solution, if there is any alternative for this please suggest that as well.

Comment: check ibaction which named stopVideoPlayer is not exist in HomeViewController . check in storyboard and remove bad connection.

Comment: It exist i have created a breakpoint to check this it crashes on this line self.avPlayer = nil

Comment: are you implemented the this method `stopVideoPlayer`

Answer (score 2):

Due to the reusable behavior of the cell, it releases the child view instance with itself so you have to stop it in the [`didEndDisplayingCell`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614870-tableview) delegate method.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = cell as? MyCustomCell {
        if let play = player {
           print("stopped")
           play.pause()
           player = nil
           print("player deallocated")
        } else {
           print("player was already deallocated")
        }
    }
}
```

OR

You can get the cell instance and search the player instance and stop it.

```
for view in cell.subviews {
      //after comparison stop the player here
}
```

Comment: I think linking to the method documentation would be better ;)

Comment: @Salman_Ghumsani I need to know how to stop the video that is playing? Do you know how to stop avplayer when it is playing.

Comment: thats the same code i have done above, but i'm  still not able to stop the avplayer when it is playing

Comment: You are doing it in `didEndDisplayingCell ` with if let checking?

Comment: also plz specify which statement prints?

Comment: even if the cell is visible i need to stop the video. i need to know which code let me stop the avplayer

Answer (score 1):

AVPlayer does not have stop method. So you can set seek time to 0 and pause the player.

```
videoPlayer.seek(to: CMTimeMake(0, 1))
videoPlayer.pause()
```

Moreover, If you want to check if the videoCell is Visible or not. You can use the below code which will give you array of index of cells which are visible. So you can simply check if array contains your video cell index or not.

```
tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

Comment: This code is still not working to stop the player. moreover i need to stop the player even if it is on the screen. Problem is this that code is not working to stop the player.

Comment: You have to use this code snippet like this playerLayer. videoPlayer.pause() .Because you have added videoPlayer on top of playerLayer. It might work probably